# Python Recursive Function to Check if Palindrome

Tags: python, recursion

I need to define a recursive function to check if a string is a palindrome.

Below's my code:

```
def palindrome_recur(string):

    if len(string)==0 or 1:
        return True
    else:
        if string[0] == string[-1]:
            return palindrome_recur(string[1:-2])
        else:
            return False
```

It passes a few test cases, but doesn't work for the string `"chipmunks"`. Can anybody tell me what I might have overlooked?

Comment: @MartijnPieters hardly, the OP didn't know that was the problem, and also there is another issue with the slicing of couse.

Comment: @AlexThornton: that's a small issue that could be addressed in a comment; the main issue here is the misunderstanding how `or` works. And that's exactly what the dupe addresses.

Comment: ahh, thank you so much everyone! still a beginner at programming! thank you

Comment: I think line #7 should be `return palindrome_recur(string[1:-1])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
if len(string)==0 or 1:
```

That checks whether either of `len(string) == 0`, or `1` is true. Since `1` is always true, the whole expression is always true and your function always returns True.

You should use

```
if len(string) <= 1:
```

instead.

Then, you'll find out about the problem with indexing to -2 that the other answers mention.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I'm still a beginner at programming. Guess I missed out on that bit!

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the recursive call as: `return palindrome_recur(string[1:-1])` instead.

Also, your `len` check is not correct. Do this instead:

```
if len(strg)==0 or len(strg)==1:
```